# How to hide parent if it has only one child visible?

Tags: html, jquery, css

How to hide parent element (or particular child element) if it has only one element, in this case button visible, and the other children is set to display:none;

```
<div class="buttons">
<button class="button">
1
</button>
<button style="display:none;" class="button">
2
</button>
<button style="display:none;" class="button">
3
</button>
<button style="display:none;" class="button">
4
</button>
<button style="display:none;" class="button">
5
</button>
</div>
```

I have tried using something like:

```
.buttons:nth-child(2):not([style*="display: none"] {
  display: none;
}
```

I would like to know both solutions, to set `.buttons` to `display:none;`, as well as how to set only element, in this case `button` to `display:none;`.

Does not matter if it can't be done by css, I can use jquery too.

Comment: If there is only one visible child is it always the first child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSS-only way, but it is subtle, ugly and [not very well supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has):

```css
.buttons:not(:has(> :not([style*="display: none"]) ~ :not([style*="display: none"]))) {
  display: none;
}
```

Try it:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const _2ndButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button')[1];

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    _2ndButton.style.display = '';
  } else {
    _2ndButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons:not(:has(> :not([style*="display: none"]) ~ :not([style*="display: none"]))) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Toggle <code>display</code> of second child:
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">
    1
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
   2
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    3
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    4
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    5
  </button>
</div>
```

Using JS is a better choice, although you may have to take `visibility`/`opacity`/etc. into account too:

```js
function toggleParent() {
  const visibleChildren = $parent
    .children()
    .filter(function(_, element) {
      // :visible cannot be used since the child will always be hidden if its parent already is.
      return window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none';
    });
  
  if (visibleChildren.length > 1) {
    $parent.css('display', '');
  } else {
    $parent.css('display', 'none');
  }
}
```

Try it:

```js
const $parent = $('.buttons');

function toggleParent() {
  const visibleChildren = $parent
    .children()
    .filter(function(_, element) {
      return window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none';
    });

  if (visibleChildren.length > 1) {
    $parent.css('display', '');
  } else {
    $parent.css('display', 'none');
  }
}

toggleParent();

// Demo only

const $input = $('input');
const $2ndButton = $('.button').eq(1);

$input.change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $2ndButton.css('display', '');
  } else {
    $2ndButton.css('display', 'none');
  }
  toggleParent();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Toggle <code>display</code> of second child:
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">
    1
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
   2
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    3
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    4
  </button>
  <button style="display: none;" class="button">
    5
  </button>
</div>
```